# Create WebDAV network drive and use it in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, webdav

**My Web Server Machine includes:**

1. IIS 7.
2. Windows server 2008.
3. WebDAV Network Drive mapped as Z drive which of another windows 2008 server.
4. ASP.NET MVC application hosted on server machine.

The user which I used in IIS for web application, is also provided permissions on to the WebDAV(*this is service account in the same domain*).

I am able to create Z drive map for WebDAV running NET USE command from command window, here question is that.
While the same created Z drive is not accessible from ASP.NET MVC application,

> it throws Could not find a part of the path 'Z:\uploadfolder\'

And how can I grammatically create WebDAV's Z drive and access this from ASP.NET MVC application?

Comment: this could be of some help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2202164/how-can-i-access-a-networked-drive-via-the-web

Comment: This is something that you can use as a reference https://www.hanselman.com/blog/AccessingMappedNetworkDrivesViaASPNETInIIS6.aspx